# How actually Swing reuses native window of HeavyWeight Ancestor in code level

Tags: swing

If Swing is totally written in Java and it reuses the window of heavyweight(HW) ancestor, what is the logic behind it?
I mean , if swing extends HW component class , then , again HW components would be calling native calls , so somehow native calls is getting called.
But swing is light weight , so where my understanding is getting failed?

Answer (score 0):

The native components into which Swing graphics are drawn are not a part of the Java class hierarchy.  There *are* certain components which are referred to as heavyweight, but only because their graphics backing more or less directly corresponds to a native component.

Most Swing components paint into a buffer provided by a heavyweight ancestor in the visual hierarchy; that heavyweight ancestor is responsible for moving the Java-drawn graphics out to the native component for display.

Comment: but finally the drawing is being carried out in the native environment , only thing is now an interface is there in between to process this step , and if this buffer is responsible for graphics drawing so is it like drawing graphics in Heavyweight and lightweight components , both takes almost same time or both can be considered as expensive

Comment: Beyond what I've described, it's up to the AWT internal implementation to determine where and when native operations are applied.  Some implementations might simply copy an image buffer, some may translate Graphics2D requests into native graphics primitives on the available canvas.